# Generate /users/me url with viewset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

viewset will generate below urls

```
/users/
/users/[PK]
```

@detail_route can generate below urls

```
/users/[PK]/me
```

My question is how to generate /users/me url based on viewset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of url's use [list_route](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).

```
@list_route
def me(self, request):
   me_user = request.user
   ... serialize user and return ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
from rest_framework import status

@list_route(methods=['get'], url_path='me')
def me(self, request, pk=None):
    '''
    Your code
    '''

    return Response({'status': 'success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```